# Exclude the WCF ServiceBehaviorExtension for one particular endpoint

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior, endpointbehavior

I would like to exclude the custom Behavior extension which expects a custom Header for one of my service. Is it possible? I read about RemoveBehaviorExtension element but there is no mention on where to use it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i had earlier created a separate Endpoint behavior with out the BehaviorExtensions node. But it failed, when examined further it was a timeout exception which was troubling me still. Modified the external client with an increased timeout and modified my service to have the endpoint with a seperate Endpoint behavior the issue got resolved. Thanks!